# Merge 2 audio files in sox

Tags: merge, sox

I am trying to merge 2 wave files into one file. The 2 files should start playing at the beginning of the new file. Independently of sound length. Running the following command does not give me this result.

```
  sox -M new_input.wav myrecording.wav output_test.aiff
```

Are there other ways of achieving this through sox or other command line libraries?

Answer (score 10):

just change `-M with -m`

```
-M = merge
-m = mix
```

Comment: Do you know any option to make it stop at the end of the shortest file?

Answer (score 7):

For cases like Calmarius is asking:

```
sox -m in1.wav in2.wav out.wav trim 0 `soxi -D in1.wav`
```

this stops at the length of in1.wav, for cases you know the shorter. Otherwise just add a comparator.

Comment: what is the function of ``soxi -D in1.wav``?

Comment: `soxi -D in1.wav` outputs the length in seconds of in1.wav. However, to run this command within the mix command you'd need to use:
 
`sox -m in1.wav in2.wav out.wav trim 0 "$(soxi -D in1.wav)"`

Comment: Is there a way to make it _repeat_ the shorter file for the duration of the longer?

Answer (score 3):

Heythere. Sorry for late response =)
Command should look like this

```
sox file1 file2 file3
```

Above will merge first two files and name it after 3rd.

You also might wanna check the docs
http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Comment: this will concatenate two files, not merge them (if by merge we talk about playing two or more files at the same time)

Comment: it just so happens i needed concatenation and this helped me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

'soxi -D in1.wav' gets the length of the file (in1.wav)